# Django Pytest Test URL Based on Settings

Tags: python, django, pytest, urlconf

I have an endpoint `/docs` in django that I only want to be visible when `DEBUG = True` in settings - otherwise, it should throw a 404. My setup looks like this

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = ...

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += [
            url(r'^docs/$', SwaggerSchemaView.as_view(), name='api_docs'),
    ]
```

When doing testing, though, django doesn't automatically reload `urls.py`, which means simply overriding `DEBUG` to `True` or `False` doesn't work.

My tests look something like this

```
@override_settings(DEBUG=True)
@override_settings(ROOT_URLCONF='config.urls')
class APIDocsTestWithDebug(APITestCase):
    # check for 200s
    ...

@override_settings(DEBUG=False)
@override_settings(ROOT_URLCONF='config.urls')
class APIDocsTestWithoutDebug(APITestCase):
    # check for 404s
    ...
```

Now here's the weird part: When I run the tests individually using `pytest path/to/test.py::APIDocsTestWithDebug` and `pytest path/to/test.py::APIDocsTestWithoutDebug`, both tests pass. However, if I run the test file as a whole (`pytest path/to/test.py`), `APIDocsTestWithDebug` always fails. The fact that *they work individually* but not together tells me that the *url override is working*, but when the tests are in tandem, there is some bug that messes things up. I was wondering if anybody had come across a similar issue and either has an entirely different solution or can give me some tips as to what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: I wouldn't say so - that question is an issue with the core functionality of overriding settings - my issue is that, while I can get `DEBUG` to be overridden, my urls are defined based on whether or not `DEBUG` is True. I need a find a way to re-generate the URLs, or something similar

Comment: How are you importing settings in `urls.py`?

Comment: `from django.conf import settings`

Comment: I'll take down the flag. You're right about it being a different issue.

Comment: You can try using `include`

Answer (score 14):

I struggled with the same issue. The thing is that Django loads your `urlpatterns` once while initializing - and overriding the settings with the decorator doesn't change what was initially loaded.

Here's what worked for me - try reloading your `urls` module (based on [this](http://codeinthehole.com/tips/how-to-reload-djangos-url-config/)) and clearing url caches with `clear_url_caches()` before the failing test cases:

```
import sys

from importlib import reload, import_module

from django.conf import settings
from django.core.urlresolvers import clear_url_caches  # Or -> from django.urls import clear_url_caches

def reload_urlconf(urlconf=None):
    clear_url_caches()
    if urlconf is None:
        urlconf = settings.ROOT_URLCONF
    if urlconf in sys.modules:
        reload(sys.modules[urlconf])
    else:
        import_module(urlconf)
```

PS: You might also want to restore the urlpatterns later - just run `reload_urlconf` within other `settings`.

Comment: Thank you, great answer.

Comment: this is correct. url registry loads only once both in a test suite and on app run. so the initial urlpatterns (based off the env var) on load won't change even if you change the env var at run time. you can change the env var then reload but make sure to revert it assuming reseting state is the intention.

Comment: This did it for me, in newer versions of django, you need to use `from django.urls import clear_url_caches` instead of from `django.core.urlresolvers`

Comment: great answer I've done a pypi package based on this code, but using a context manager for loading on enter and reloading on exit

github: https://github.com/karpyncho/reload-urls
installing: pip install karpyncho_reload_urls

Answer (score 4):

You can use `@pytest.mark.urls`: https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/helpers.html#pytest.mark.urls

```
@pytest.mark.urls('myapp.test_urls')
def test_something(client):
    assert 'Success!' in client.get('/some_url_defined_in_test_urls/').content
```

You could even define the URLs within the same file:

```
def some_view(request):
    return HttpResponse(b"Success!")


urlpatterns = [
    path("some-url/", some_view)
]


@pytest.mark.urls(__name__)
def test_something(client):
    assert b'Success!' in client.get('/some-url/').content
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on Sergei Nikiforov's Answer I have implemented a Pypi package with a context manager for loading/reloading urls

Github Page: https://github.com/karpyncho/reload-urls

Install:

```bash
pip install karpyncho_reload_urls
```

then you simply inherits your `TestCase` suit class from `TestCaseReloadableURL`

and you can simply use:

```py
from karpyncho.reload_urls import TestCaseReloadableURL
 
class TestMyClass(TestCaseReloadableURL)
    def my_test(self):
        with self.reload_urls(DEBUG=True):
            # put your checks here
```

that will reload your settings only in the context block

you are free to propose improvements...